# can the clause "...which are ..." omit in writing

Tags: conjunctions, clauses

Here my ideas:

> 1. The geometric reconstruction of object models is carried out in a way
>      to propagate errors from inner to outer bounds.
> 2. outer bounds are enforced with orientation and placement regularities.

When I join them, if I write it as

> The geometric reconstruction of object models is carried out in a way
>   to propagate errors from inner to outer bounds **which are** enforced
>   with orientation and placement regularities.

I hope this is correct.

My question is, can I omit "which are" and continue like, "... bounds enforced..."?

Comment: ***No!*** Don't use "which are" to join these two sentences! There's no reason not to leave them as separate sentences anyway, and if you try to join them like that it will likely be misinterpreted as meaning statement #1 applies ***only*** to those particular outer boundaries that *happen* to be thus enforced. Unless you've got a good reason to stitch two sentences together, don't. There is no good reason in this case.

Comment: @FumbleFingers:ok in that sense, can i use "and" to join them as i am running out of word count.. so want to breif anyhow.

Comment: I must be honest - I don't understand what your text actually *means*. Grammatically speaking, *...is carried out in a way to propagate errors...* should actually be *...is carried out **in such a way as to** propagate errors...* But I'm not sure there's any reason to mention that anyway, so I don't see why you can't just replace that entire text with ***propagates** errors*. That should reduce your word count enough. I see no point in saying *X is carried out in such a way as to do Y*, when you can just as easily say *X does Y*, especially if wordcount is an issue.

Comment: Maybe use "the latter": "...inner and outer bounds, the latter enforced with orientation and placement regularities."

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically,  “which are” can be left out in the combination sentence.  But as a practical matter, whether to use “which are” or leave it out is not the problem.  Both of the original sentences are clumsy and unclear, and the combination still more so.  Consider rewriting in a form like

> Errors propagate from inner to outer bounds when objects are reconstructed.  Objects are  orientated and placed to comply with outer bounds.

(The rewritten example might not have the meaning you intended, because I don't understand what the originals mean.)